# svnkit: how to enumerate svn repositories in a root directory?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

How do you use svnkit to enumerate svn repositories in a root directory?

Comment: Have you already looked through this? 
https://wiki.svnkit.com/Managing_Repository_With_SVNKit

Comment: How does that help? I'm talking about multiple svn repositories beneath one root directory. As far as I can tell SVNKit gives you lots of features once you know a particular repository's path, but I can't find an enumerate-repository feature.

Answer (score 2):

I think (I worked with svn kit 1 year ago) you have to manually list all directories next to your repository path:

So if your repopath is:

```
/var/svn/myrepo
```

you should list

```
/var/svn/
```

and check all directories by connecting to them (just try to svn ls)

Comment: that's what I ended up doing... you still have to try doing some svnkit operation and be prepared for it to throw an exception if a subdirectory is not an svn repository. It would have been cleaner if they had a way of testing/enumerating a directory w/o throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about svnkit but consider performing a recursive search for a svn file that indicates the presence of a svn repository...

I forget the structure of a svn repo but look for hidden files and folders that start with ".".  I think .svn is a hidden folder that indicates a svn repo?